# Clipping Graphs in MATLAB 2013b

Tags: matlab

My plot currently extends beyond the specified axis limits.  As MATLAB documents [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-is-part-of-the-graph-cut-off.html), this is the default for 2013b (the version I'm using).  It seems I want to set `'Clipping','3dbox'` but that doesn't seem to work (perhaps it isn't available in 2013b).  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image: protruding image]

Comment: The `ClippingStyle`-property is not available in 2013b. It got intruduced in 2014b with the new graphical engine. The `clipping`-property exists already in 2013b but has no effect on axis and figures. Apply it on the surface-handle instead to get what you want. Alternatively check out this [article on MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63516-surf-and-xlim-ylim-setting-the-limits-on-a-3d-graph-doesnt-seem-to-work). I don't have Version 2013b installed to give you a finalized solution.

Comment: @ Matt Like this? `surf(y,x,z,'Clipping','3dbox')`?  Or `set(gcf,'Clipping','3dbox')`?  Neither seemed to work :/

Comment: No, in 2013b the `clipping`-property can only be `on` or `off`. You need to do something like this: `s = surf(y,x,z); set(s,'Clipping','on')`. I don't know if you can set this property directly using `surf(y,x,z,'Clipping','on')`, it's worth a try.

Comment: @Matt No luck, but thanks for the idea.  No luck with this listener idea from the link, either.  It seems like plotting in MATLAB leaves a lot to be desired :/

Comment: Try to implement the concept without the listeners. Call the statements manually only to crop the z-data and write it back. I think that must definitely work...